# updating data.table in a for loop and with a grouping variable

Tags: r, data.table

I want to update some columns in a data.table within a for loop. The column names are set dynamically. Unfortunately, the solution I use is ridiculously slow and thus not viable. I have tried everything I found about this subject but nothing seems to make it faster.

My dataset has 682446 rows. What seems to make it so slow are the dynamic column names. When I use the static version, it works very fine and in light speed:

```
dt[education>0, educationNewVersion:=education]
```

The problem arises when the variable names in i, j (LHS, RHS) are dynamic:

```
varName = 'education'
newVarName <- paste0(varName, 'NewVersion')

# This is much slower as the static version from above, takes almost half a minute.
dt[dt[[varName]]>0, (newVarName):=get(varName)]
# This is very slow too
dt[dt[[varName]]>0, (newVarName):=eval(varName)]
# This one throws an error (see below)
dt[dt[[varName]]>0, (newVarName):=dt[[varName]]]
```

This is the error thrown by the third expression:
"Supplied 682446 items to be assigned to 76451 items of column 'gerSpeakImp'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code."

Please don't propose that I should use set(). set() does not support grouping and I need to group (I just haven't included here to keep the examples simple). I have no idea what else to do. Currently I am updating every column with an own statement which is really very redundant and which is not what I expected when I moved from Stata to R (and to data.table).

Comment: Have you tried with `.SDcols` i.e. `dt[, (newVarName) := .SD[[1]], .SDcols = varName]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to use `.I` and `.SDcols`.

```
dt[dt[, .I[.SD[[1]] > 0], .SDcols = varName], (newVarName) := .SD[[1]], 
       .SDcols = varName]
```

---

In the third expression, error occured because it is trying to subset the column from the whole dataset where the length is different.  Instead, we could use `.SD`

```
dt[dt[[varName]]>0, (newVarName):= .SD[[varName]]]
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
dt <- data.table(education = sample(0:50, 682446, replace = TRUE))
dt1 <- copy(dt)

varName <- 'education'
newVarName <- paste0(varName, 'NewVersion')

system.time(dt[dt[[varName]]>0, (newVarName):= .SD[[varName]]])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.022   0.003   0.026 

system.time(  dt1[dt1[, .I[.SD[[1]] > 0], .SDcols = varName],
     (newVarName) := .SD[[1]], 
            .SDcols = varName])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.023   0.003   0.024
```

Comment: @MaikSchürmann may be the system specs are differnt.  I used OSX `32 GB memory` and `2.3 GHz`

Comment: This is very strange, I have tried all three of your proposed versions and they were very different in regard of their speed:  `system.time(dt[dt[[varName]]>0,(newVarName):=.SD[[varName]]])  
   # user  system elapsed   
  # 3.627  16.228  34.008  

system.time(dt[dt[[varName]]>0, (newVarName):=.SD[[1]], .SDcols = varName])  
   #user  system elapsed   
  #0.009   0.004   0.012   

system.time(dt[dt[, .I[.SD[[1]] > 0], .SDcols=varName], (newVarName):=.SD[[1]], .SDcols=varName])  
   #user  system elapsed   
  #0.012   0.004   0.021`  
OSX with 2,4 GHz DualCore Intel Core i5 & 8GB

Comment: @MaikSchürmann i see that your memory is 8GB.  I used 32GB..  Also, the data I created have only a single column.  If you have lots of columns, then it could also have some impact

Comment: This was my guess too. Thanks for your time!